# how not to query twice while using SSR and Dynamic Metadata

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am using Next.js 13 with App routing system, as you see in the code. I set FetchingProudct which is SSR. It calls an API for both generateMetaData which is dynamic metadata and one for sending data props to use client page component. I feel afraid that the fetchingProduct might run twice. I wrapped with react cache, but I am not sure whether it works. Are there any better approach or anything to fix?

````
import { use,cache } from 'react'
import ProductDetail from '../components/ProductDetail';

const FetchingProduct = cache(async({id})=> {
    const response = await fetch(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/${id}`,
        {cache : 'no-store'}
    );
    return response.json()
  });

const FetchingRecommnandProduct = cache(async({id})=> {
    const response = await fetch(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/recommandation/${id}`,
        {cache : 'no-store'}
    );
    return response.json()
  });


export async function generateMetadata({ params, searchParams }, parent) {
  // read route params
  const id = params.id
  
  // fetch data
  const product = await FetchingProduct({id})

  // optionally access and extend (rather than replace) parent metadata
  const previousImages = (await parent).openGraph?.images || []
  
  return {
    title: product?.name,
    description: product?.description,
    openGraph: {
      images: [`http://127.0.0.1:8000${product?.images[0]?.image}`, ...previousImages],
    },
  }
}


  export default function Product({ params }) {
    const {id} = params
    const productData = use(FetchingProduct({id}))
    const recommandProductData = use(FetchingRecommnandProduct({id}))
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductDetail 
        product={productData}
        recommandProduct={recommandProductData}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }```


I wrapped my SSR function with react cache, but I am not sure that it fetches once and can be used for multiple places. Any better approaches for that?
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching same api using fetch() on server, Nextjs will cache fetch requests that have the same input and reuse them. You don't have to worry about.
[source here..](https://dev.to/zenstack/a-deep-dive-into-next13-data-fetching-114n#:%7E:text=Automatically%20deduped%20fetch)

Comment: oh really? thank you so much so cahce() is not necessary isn't it?

Comment: I am not sure about it but I think it is not necessary. I recommend you reading official docs about [Request Memorization](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#request-memoization)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).